# Context Free Grammar Exercise

Tags: context-free

I'm studying Context free Grammar and I have a question to a specific Exercise:

[image]

Why is **i.** True? How is this possible?

Comment: By the way, it is CS.SE policy to post text as text, not as an image. Here, you only needed the grammar plus the (i) item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every nonterminal $A$ it *always* holds that $A \Rightarrow^* A$. This is because $\Rightarrow^*$ is the *reflexive* transitive closure of $\Rightarrow$. In words, $A \Rightarrow^* \alpha$ is $\alpha$ can be obtained from $A$ by applying *zero* or more productions.

The similar notation $\Rightarrow^+$ is the transitive closure of $\Rightarrow$, and corresponds to *one* or more productions. In your grammar, it isn't the case that $T \Rightarrow^+ T$.