# Use or Importance of $\Rightarrow^*$ operator

Tags: context-free, derivation

Particularly, there are 2 variants of $\Rightarrow$, one is $\Rightarrow^*$ and another is $\Rightarrow^+$ which are used in derivation of strings using the productions of the grammar.

As stated [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93388/context-free-grammar-exercise#93403), when $\Rightarrow^*$ is used, it means *derive in 0 or more steps* and when $\Rightarrow^+$ is used, it means *derive in 1 or more steps*.

What I don't understand is **what is the use or importance of $\Rightarrow^*$ operator?**. It just replaces the head of the production with the head itself.
*Is it that the $\Rightarrow^*$ operator is just there to define operators in some standard way or it actually differs in the way it is used as compared to $\Rightarrow^+$?*

Also, while deriving strings, to skip some obivious steps(like replacing multiple non-terminals in a string with their respective terminals), **should I use $\Rightarrow^*$ or $\Rightarrow^+$?**

Answer (score 2):

It is false that $\Rightarrow^*$ " just replaces the head of the production with the head itself". $A \Rightarrow^* B$ means that the sentential form $B$ can be obtained from the sentimental form $A$ by applying **any** number of productions (which might be $0$ or more than $0$).

For example if your grammar is $S \to a$, then all of the following are true  $S \Rightarrow^* S$, $S \Rightarrow^* a$, and $S \Rightarrow^+ a$, while it is false that $S \Rightarrow^+ S$.

If you are deriving strings and applying *at least one* production per step then both $\Rightarrow^*$ and $\Rightarrow^+$ are correct. The latter is more specific since it implies the former (but not vice-versa).

Comment: According to you, "the sentential form B can be obtained from the sentential form A by applying any number of productions (which might be 0 or more than 0)", so in case of applying no productions while deriving a new string, *I infer it means that the new derived string will be **same as before.***
So, if my inference is correct then, **what is the significance of this reflexive property of $\Rightarrow^*$ operator?**

Comment: $A \Rightarrow^* B$ is just a notation to mean that $B$ can be derived from $A$ in some way. You use it when you want to express that... Consider a sample grammar $G$ defined as follows $S \to A|B, \quad A \to Aa | a, \quad B \to AA$. The following statement would be true: $\forall$ sentential form $X$, there exist a sentence $y \in a^*$ such that $X \Rightarrow^* y$. But the following statement would be false: $\forall$ sentential form $X$, there exist a sentence $y \in a^*$ such that $X \Rightarrow^+ y$.

Comment: ok, so, does it mean the operator $\Rightarrow^*$ is required (if that's the correct word) to have a more comprehensive definition of the symbols??